# Coordinate geometry: calculating the height of an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry

If I have equilateral $\Delta ABC$ with A being $(-x,0)$ and B being $(x,0)$, how can I solve for the coordinates of C in terms of $x$?

I tried the following:

$2x^2 = x^2 + b^2 $ -- pythagorean thm, since we know that one side of the triangle is two times the length of half of the base.

$3x^2 = b^2$ -- simplification

$ x\sqrt3 = b $ -- so this says that the height of point C must be x\sqrt3 units.

<strike>This gives me an end result with the coordinates $(0, 2)$. However, frankly, this doesn't seem logical to me...what I'm basically saying with that result is that *all* equilateral triangles are two units tall...**what**?! This sounds completely incorrect.</strike>

Any help would be great; thanks.

**edited**: I actually had the right idea, I just made a stupid mistake with my simplification. ._.

Comment: $(2x)^2 = x^2 + b^2$.

Comment: You guys are so fast...

Comment: Hmmm ... Maybe the "$(2x)^2$" thing was a typo on your part. It *seems* like you might have gone from $4 x^2 = x^2 + b^2$ (a correct statement) to $4 = b^2$ (an incorrect simplification). To isolate $b^2$, subtract $x^2$ from both sides: $4x^2 - x^2 = b^2$, and note that the left-hand side reduces to $3x^2$, **not** $4$. ($4 x^2 - x^2 = 4 x^2 - 1x^2 = (4 - 1 )x^2 = 3 x^2$ ... That is: four copies of $x^2$, take-away one copy of $x^2$, leaves three copies of $x^2$.)

Comment: @Blue, you're entirely correct--it was purely a typo on my part. However, the answers below are incredibly informative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the triangle is equilateral, the $x$-coordinate of $C$ must be $x=0$, so that it falls in the middle of the $x$-coordinates of $A$ and $B$.

The base has length $|AB|=2x$ and so all of the sides have length $2x$. The point $C$ will lie on the circle, centre $A$ and radius $2x$. The whole circle is parametrized by $(-x,0) + 2x(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, where $\theta = 0$ corresponds to the base. Since we have an equilateral triangle, we have $\theta = 60^{\circ}$:

\begin{array}{ccc}
(-x,0)+2x(\cos 60, \sin 60) &=& (-x,0) + 2x(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) \\ \\
&=& (0,x\sqrt{3})
\end{array}

If you want an "inverted" triangle then let $C=(0,-x\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: There are 2 possibilities for the point $C$ ...

Comment: @CalvinLin True enough. I've added an inverted triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a diagram and you will how the triangle works out.

In an equilateral triangle all sides are equal. Thus, the hypotenuse of your right angle triangle is $2x$. Let the third coordinate be represented by $(0,c)$. You should reason out as to why the $X$ coordinate of point $C$ is $0$.

Therefore, it follows that:

$c^2 + x^2 = (2x)^2$

Therefore, $c$ = ----

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have the base vertices of your equilateral triangle at ( -x, 0 ) and ( x, 0 ) , so the altitude of your triangle lies on the y-axis at what you are calling ( 0, b ) .  That makes the base of either of the right triangles you are using $ \ x \ $ , but then the hypotenuse of your triangle (a side of the equilateral triangle) has length $ \ 2x \ $ .  Therefore, the set-up using the Pythagorean Theorem must be

$$ (2x)^2  =  x^2 + b^2 . $$

You need to square that 2x ...

Answer (score 0):

Since the coordinates of the equilateral triangle is in terms of $x$, the answer will be as well, because it depends on the length of each sides, right ?

It's actually not too hard to find it, but let me show you a trick and an important theorem that we use in order to solve this problem.

> 1), The altitude of any isosceles triangle is the median, the angle bisector of top angle and the perpendicular bisector.
>
> 2), An equilateral triangle is a special case of an isosceles.

This should tell you that the altitude, which lies on the $y$-axis in your case, will not only be perpendicular to the base, but it will also bisect the top angle. This forms a 30-60-90 triangle which you must have learned in geometry.

So, if you want to find the height, just use the $1$-$2$-$\sqrt{3}$ ratio.

Does this help ?